# Nightwatch XML output file is empty

Tags: nightwatch.js

When I run my test, I get all the output I would expect from the test such as

```
 ✔ Element <body> was visible after 12 milliseconds.
 ✔ Testing if element <input[id="usernameID"]> is visible.
 ✔ Testing if element <#usernameID> is visible.
 ✔ Testing if element <#passwordID> is visible.
 ✔ Testing if value of <#usernameID> contains: "".
```

But when I open the XML file that is generated there is nothing there, just the header, footer and a bunch of blank lines.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<testsuites errors="0"
            failures="0"
            tests="2">

  <testsuite name="loginTests"
    errors="0" failures="0" hostname="" id="" package="login" skipped="0"
    tests="2" time="15.87" timestamp="Mon, 08 Feb 2016 21:01:16 GMT">

    <testcase name="Login Page Load Test" time="10.68" assertions="1">


    </testcase>

    <testcase name="Login/Logout Test" time="5.195" assertions="23">







    </testcase>


  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Here is a snippet of the code.

```
'Login/Logout Test' : function(client) {
  client
   .waitForElementVisible("body", client.globals.waitForConditionTimeout)
   .assert.visible('input[id="usernameID"]')
   .assert.visible('#usernameID')
   .assert.visible('#passwordID')
   .end
```

I must be missing something simple.

Comment: Would you post the code of the test cases that generates said output?

Comment: added snipit of code for you

Comment: Would you also post the code that creates your output XML file? I would look here to verify you're writing the values, you are looking for, to the file.

Comment: I am running the following at the command prompt... my understanding of the nightwatch code was that the XML file would be populated.  "node nightwatch -a login -r junit -o report"... is this not the case? do I have to manually write output XML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is the way it is... does not make a lot of sense but...

To get this information out of the test run a custom reporter is used.

I have done this, now I can write the information anywhere I want I chose to write it to a DB table.

Comment: How did you do it ? I know it's been a while, but I am facing the same issue, and nightwatch doc is pretty bad about this subject

Comment: @SuperMarco it has been a while indeed... I am pretty sure this what I finally ended up using.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/nightwatch-html-reporter